# Prioritize a function in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on an angular apllication and have a asynchronous function (from a library I am using). Now I would like to tell my program to finish the function of the library and only when the function has finished proceed with the rest of the program. Is there a way to prioritize functions in typescript?

```js
// Take next tourStep
        this.tourService.next();
        if (stepId === 4) {
            const backdrop = document.querySelector('.ngx-tour_backdrop') as HTMLElement;
        }
```

The code above shows my problem the this.tourService.next(); dynamically creates an HTMLElement which I afterwards would like to select to perform certain actions on it. However the called function isn't finished by the time the selector tries to find the HTML element. Is there a way to bypass this issue?

Comment: Usually this is not have things are done. 
If this function is async, it should either accept callback as argument, return promise or service it belongs to should fire some event for client to know it finished working.

Comment: if its `async` you could either use a `callback` or `promise` if it supports them. What does the `api` of your async function looks like of the library you are using?

Comment: Learn about promises.

Comment: Or you can use the async/await pattern https://javascript.info/async-await

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on the context. First, check if tourService.next() accepts an optional callback argument or returns the promise itself. Now, there are three possible scenarios. A), there exists a callback argument. B) It returns a promise. C) Neither.

In case of A, provide a callback and put your code in there.

In case of B, add the callback to the Promise.

In case of C, you could go for a hack and continuously check (with an interval) whether it has finished. This is suboptimal due to inefficiency and... well, being a hack. It should only be a last resort.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I managed the solve the issue in a completely different way. But you answer seems to make the most sense. Guess I'll have to start learning about promises and callbacks for a next situation.

Answer (score 0):

Usually async functions have a callback function where you can place code that needs to execute after the async function finishes .Does the `next()` function not have that?